# How can I append XSLT value with XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I generate XML node from XSLT xsl:for-each loop?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//aaa/bbb">
      <section name="HOW CAN I INSERT THERE //aaa/bbb//ccc?">
        <xsl:for-each select="//aaa/bbb[xxx=101]">
          <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="ParameterName"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </section>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

You question isn't completely clear, but do you mean:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//aaa/bbb">
      <section>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select=".//ccc"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="//aaa/bbb[UtilityDefinitionsID=101]">
          <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="ParameterName"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </section>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

(Untested, as there's no example of the xml you're trying to process)

Comment: Thanks. But no, I'd like to generate node <section> with name which will include value from this element "//aaa/bbb//ccc".

Comment: Amended. Note that .//ccc should get //aaa/bbb//ccc for the current //aaa/bbb node that you're looping on.

Answer (score 1):

@Jon Egerton should be your answer, perhaps you want:

```
  <section>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="ccc"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="//aaa/bbb[UtilityDefinitionsID=101]">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="ParameterName"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </section>
```

Comment: I would also use an AVT for the `name` attribute: `<section name="{ccc}">`